# Determine for which values of $(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)$ is the following vector field Hamiltonian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The vector field is given as:

$x' = −\mu y + ax^3 + bx^2y+cxy^2+dy^3$

$y' = \mu x + ex^3 + fx^2y + gxy^2 + hy^3$

So what steps do I need to take. Do I need to compute the Hamiltonian function first?

Comment: If you  have a Hamiltonian system with Hamiltonian $H(x, y)$, then it must be of form $\dot{x} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}, \; \dot{y} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$. If you have a system of form $\dot{x} = M(x, y), \; \dot{y} = N(x, y)$, do you see what necessary conditions should be imposed on $M(x,  y)$ and $N(x, y)$ in order to be $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}$ and  $-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}$ respectively?

Comment: To expand on @Evgeny's comment: Suppose that your system is indeed Hamiltonian, that means that there exists a function $H(x,y)$ which gives you your system. In particular, that means that $\frac{\partial H}{\partial y} = -\mu y + a x^3 + \ldots$. From this equation, you can try to find $H(x,y)$ itself. Now, you can do the same with the equation for $\dot{y}$. Obviously, those two expressions for $H(x,y)$ you found must be equal.
Alternatively, if you assume that $H$ has a certain degree of smoothness, you can think of looking at mixed derivatives.

Comment: @FritsVeerman .... and "mixed derivatives" is what I really intended to say with my hint-like comment ;)

Comment: @Evgeny if you can post a solution I will br happy to accept

Comment: I can, but I don't think that this is a right thing to do. @FritsVeerman gave a really nice step by step explanation of what you should try. It's just five minutes of pen and paper work, you really should try it.

Comment: Why do we see no answer by the OP arriving on this page?

Comment: @Did, what do you mean exactly? do you dislike my activity on mse?

Comment: "what do you mean exactly?" See previous comment. "do you dislike my activity on mse?" Huh? No idea what you are talking about.